# Setting environment variables in a containerized environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have a Flask backend which contains some environment variables saved in a **.env** file. I have also created a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN mkdir /app
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tk \
    && pip install -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get -y clean; \
    apt-get -y autoclean; \
    apt-get -y autoremove; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY app/ /app
COPY .env /
RUN flask db init
RUN flask db migrate
RUN flask db upgrade

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --threads=2 --workers=2  app.app:app
```

I want to remove the line:

```
COPY .env /
```

since I do not want to copy my environment variables in the container. I want to put my **.env** file in a **.dockerignore** file. Is there some alternate way to use the environment variables without copying them in my dockerized environment?

I tried an alternative command on the PowerShell while running the docker image to create a container:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 --env-file .env <image-name>
```

This solution does work but I want another alternative for this. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: "*This solution does work but I want another alternative for this.*" - Why?

Comment: The other obvious alternative is bind-mounting the `.env` file into the container.

Answer (score 1):

The `--env-file` is the most elegant way to handle this situation if you don't want to (or you can't) use a `docker-compose`.

Alternatives:

1. docker-compose.yml : Pretty much the same solution but in a "file". You can create a `docker-compose.yml` file in the root of your project and fill it with something similar to:

```yaml
services:
    flask:
        image: <image-name>
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        env_file:
            - ".env"
```

Then run your container using:

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

> important: you have to install the [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) plug in first.

2. usage of `ENV` in dockerfile: Please keep in mind that if you have a really big quantity of envs this is a **bad** practice. This solution is the less attractive to most of us because it "pollutes" the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

####################
# ENV examples     #
####################
ENV http_port 80   
ENV https_port=443 

RUN mkdir /app
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tk \
    && pip install -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get -y clean; \
    apt-get -y autoclean; \
    apt-get -y autoremove; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY app/ /app
COPY .env /
RUN flask db init
RUN flask db migrate
RUN flask db upgrade

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --threads=2 --workers=2  app.app:app
```